# How to extract these values in PHP and show it in a table format?

Tags: php, stdclass

How to display above values as page wise, sorting and searching options?

stdClass Object
    (
        [totalcdrcount] => 11
        [cdrs] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [calldate] => 2014-10-31T16:02:38+05:30
                        [src] => 1111
                        [dst] => 1978
                        [channel] => SIP/1111-0000000f
                        [dstchannel] => SIP/1978-00000010
                        [disposition] => ANSWERED
                        [uniqueid] => 1414751558.15
                        [duration] => 511
                        [billsec] => 508
                        [accountcode] => 
                    )

```
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T16:02:22+05:30
                    [src] => 1111
                    [dst] => 1111
                    [channel] => SIP/1111-0000000e
                    [dstchannel] => 
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414751542.14
                    [duration] => 13
                    [billsec] => 13
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:33:22+05:30
                    [src] => 1111
                    [dst] => 1978
                    [channel] => SIP/1111-0000000c
                    [dstchannel] => SIP/1978-0000000d
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749802.12
                    [duration] => 1730
                    [billsec] => 1722
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:31:18+05:30
                    [src] => 1978
                    [dst] => 1111
                    [channel] => SIP/1978-0000000a
                    [dstchannel] => SIP/1111-0000000b
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749678.10
                    [duration] => 117
                    [billsec] => 110
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:31:04+05:30
                    [src] => 1111
                    [dst] => 1978
                    [channel] => SIP/1111-00000009
                    [dstchannel] => 
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749664.9
                    [duration] => 10
                    [billsec] => 10
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:30:30+05:30
                    [src] => 1978
                    [dst] => 1111
                    [channel] => SIP/1978-00000007
                    [dstchannel] => SIP/1111-00000008
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749630.7
                    [duration] => 28
                    [billsec] => 21
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:30:11+05:30
                    [src] => 1111
                    [dst] => 1978
                    [channel] => SIP/1111-00000005
                    [dstchannel] => SIP/1978-00000006
                    [disposition] => NO ANSWER
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749611.5
                    [duration] => 4
                    [billsec] => 0
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:29:24+05:30
                    [src] => 1111
                    [dst] => 1978
                    [channel] => SIP/1111-00000004
                    [dstchannel] => 
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749564.4
                    [duration] => 17
                    [billsec] => 17
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:28:36+05:30
                    [src] => 1978
                    [dst] => 1111
                    [channel] => SIP/1978-00000002
                    [dstchannel] => SIP/1111-00000003
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414749516.2
                    [duration] => 43
                    [billsec] => 39
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:19:18+05:30
                    [src] => 1978
                    [dst] => *97
                    [channel] => SIP/1978-00000001
                    [dstchannel] => 
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414748958.1
                    [duration] => 25
                    [billsec] => 25
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [calldate] => 2014-10-31T15:18:42+05:30
                    [src] => 1978
                    [dst] => *79
                    [channel] => SIP/1978-00000000
                    [dstchannel] => 
                    [disposition] => ANSWERED
                    [uniqueid] => 1414748922.0
                    [duration] => 4
                    [billsec] => 4
                    [accountcode] => 
                )

        )

)
```

How to display above values as page wise, sorting and searching options?

Comment: You could use: https://github.com/hakre/print_r-converter - but don't store the print_r() output in the first place. Use something that's more portable, like `var_export()` or `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over them and ouput your table...

```
<?php
if ($response->totalcdrcount > 0) {
   $fields = array();
   foreach ($response->cdrs[0] as $field => $value) {
      $fields[] = $field;
   }
}

?>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
      <th><?php echo $field ?></th>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($response->cdrs as $cdr): ?>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
        <td><?php echo isset($cdr->$field) ? $cdr->$field : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How to display above values as page wise, sorting and searching options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($object->crds as $Card) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $Card->calldate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->src; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->dst; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->channel; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->dstchannel; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->disposition; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->uniqueid; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->duration; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->billsec; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Card->accountcode; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it it really clear that you lack basic PHP knowledge so I suggest you start by reading some PHP tutorials or watch some PHP videos.

Now to answer your question

```
echo '<table>';

foreach($object->cdrs as $value) {
echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $value->calldate . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $value->src . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $value->dst . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $value->channel . '</td>';
   //etc...
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Hope this helps! :D